# Is the intersection of all intervals $\left( 0, \frac{1}{i} \right)$, where $i$ is in $\{1,2,3...\}$, equal to the empty set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, does $\big(0,\frac{1}{1}\big)\bigcap\big(0,\frac{1}{2}\big)\bigcap\big(0,\frac{1}{3}\big)\bigcap\dots = \emptyset$ ?

This has bugged me for the last couple of hours.

The question is whether $\big(0,\frac{1}{n}\big)$, when $n$ goes to infinity, is considered to be $(0,0)$ or just $(0,\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is really, really small. In the first scenario, the answer would be $\emptyset$, but in the second it would be that $\big(0,\epsilon\big)$ interval.

Basically, I don't know if in this case, you can consider $\frac{1}{\infty}$ to be equal to $0$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid considerations of $\frac{1}{\infty}$ or other a-bit-handwavy arguments that could end in confusion or mistakes, an option is to go back to the definition, or at least elementary methods:

Fix any $x \in(0,1)$. Will $x$ belong to $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (0,\frac{1}{n})$? In particular, will it belong to $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ for $n > \left\lceil\frac{1}{x}\right\rceil$?